# Position fixed menu not being centered on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a menu that is centered fine on all browsers except IE.

I've tried multiple things so far, but they mostly end up breaking when resizing the screen, the menu needs to stay centered on mobile too. The menu sticks to the top using `position: fixed;`

`margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Also doesn't work for me, how can I center the menu?

[The website I am talking about.](https://karsteninstallatie.nl/index.php)

Comment: I set `width: 100%` and it worked for my IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 11 and below acts differently for absolute/fixed positions.

Adding `width: 100%` to navbar works fine for me.

Comment: That was easy, tried everything except that! Thanks. I'll accept in 8 minutes.